# Graph x axis displaying the number of data points instead of actual x axis values for dynamic data set

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set that allows a user to add data via a userform. This is a dynamic data set that updates every few days as the user adds new data. The entered data is copied to a dummy table via formulas on the spreadsheet, which is used to create a dynamic graph using VBA. I am having two problems with this code:

1. It selects not only the cells with values, but also the empty cells containing an IF statement formula. The intent is for these to dynamically update from the main data fields.
2. The graph is correct, but the X-values are the number of data points in the set not the actual X data values.

Could someone please help me figure out why this is happening? Should I have built this in a different way? Please see the code I am using below:

```
Sub NormPerm1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NormPRange As Range
Dim NormPChart As Chart
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set StartCell = Range("AG12")

ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Set NormPChart = Charts.Add

LastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Set NormPRange = ws.Range("AG12:AG" & LastRow & ", AH12:AH" & LastRow)

With NormPChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=NormPRange
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Norm"
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
End With

'With NormPChart.Axes(xlCategory)
'.MinimumScale = ws.Range("AG13")
'.MaximumScale = ws.Range("AG72")
'End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you add `LookIn:=xlValues` to your `Find()` then it won't find formulas which don't return any value

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. When LookIn:=xlValues it graphs what is suppose to be my X axis as a second Y-axis. In this case the X axis is still just the number of data points in the set as opposed to the X axis values, which are now a second Y axis.

Comment: Is the value of `LastRow` what you expect it to be?

Comment: Have you tried: `Set NormPRange = ws.Range("AG12:AH" & LastRow)` ?

Comment: I did try it, it still graphs my AG, which should be my X-axis as another Y-axis. Then just puts the total number of data points as the X-axis.